# Cloud function throwing error while deploying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am getting below mentioned error while deploying the cloud function

I am using the latest version for cloud storage in requirements.txt
Also, I am using list_blob functionality of storage client and since then I am facing below error while deploying the function

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. 
Error message: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
Detailed stack trace:
from datetime import datetime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 315, in check_
or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 190, in load_u
ser_function
    spec.loader.exec_module(main_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 52, in <module>
    CS = storage.Client()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 129, in __init__
    self._connection = Connection(self, **kw_args)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py", line 35, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Please include your code so that we may help. The stacktrace suggests that you're incorrectly calling a function with an incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: also please share the command that you are using to deploy your funcion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works perfectly when wrapped in the [correct HTTP function format](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python)

```
#Your function
def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    from google.cloud import storage
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    fileList = []
    for blob in blobs:
        fileList.append(blob.name)
    return fileList

#function wrapper
def test_list_blob(request):
    ret = list_blobs('temp-veolia-export')
    return str(ret),200
```

And to deploy

```
gcloud functions deploy --trigger-http --entry-point=test_list_blob --runtime=python37 \
  --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated python-test-storage
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried the below mentioned code but I am wondering does cloud function supports gsutil  import subprocess
FileListTemp = []
FileList = []
FileListTemp = subprocess.check_output(["gsutil", "ls", "gs://test"]).splitlines()
FileList = [filename.replace('gs://prjadhav_test/', '') for filename in FileListTemp]

Comment: No, Cloud Functions is serverless and  you can't rely on a potential binary installed on the underlying infrastructure. However, you can do this with Cloud Run. The underlying infrastructure is the same as Cloud Functions, but, because you run a container, you can install what you want in the container, gcloud sdk included

Comment: Hi, I am using pubsub as my trigger for cloud function so will that make any difference. Earlier I had 1.13.1 as storage version, I changed it to 1.30.1 but still it is throwing same error. 
Can you help replicating the same scenario for pubsub

Comment: Pubsub trigger change nothing except the function signature!